# Hooking functions on Linux via .def file

Tags: c++, linux, dll, shared-libraries, hook

On Windows in a .def file, I can hook functions like so:

```
glAccum                    =    Hook_glAccum;
glActiveTextureARB         =    Hook_glActiveTextureARB;
glAlphaFunc                =    Hook_glAlphaFunc;
glAreTexturesResident      =    Hook_glAreTexturesResident;
glArrayElement             =    Hook_glArrayElement;
```

This way, all calls to `glAccum` are redirected to `Hook_glAccum`. All calls to `glArrayElement` are redirected to `Hook_glArrayElement` and so on..

I am not able to find the linux equivalent of a .def file or the equivalent of doing the above. Any ideas how I can achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result at run-time with LD_PRELOAD and weak symbols.
Here are a few tutorials to demonstrate:

[Understand Weak Symbols by Examples](http://winfred-lu.blogspot.com/2009/11/understand-weak-symbols-by-examples.html)

[Simple LD_PRELOAD Tutorial](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/)